# grep data between 2 patterns in shell scripting

Tags: shell, sed, grep

What command must be used to grep items between 2 matching patterns from a file. 
My file has lines like:

```
abc def ghi
abc bcd def (task Name: example)
##some other similar lines##
```

I need the data between Name: and ')'

I tried with the command

```
cat script.log | sed 's/Name:\(.*\)\)/\1/gp'
```

This command is not providing me with required result. Please guide me with this.

Also, is it possible to use $Name in place of "Name:" (using a variable that substitutes the original value)

Comment: `\)` represents the end of a grouping `)` represents a right paren. Unless you use the extended regexp switch in which case the reverse is true.

Comment: what to do if I need to get the word between "task" and "name".
I tried var="task:" 
sed -n "s/^${var}(.*)).*/\1/" but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
cat script.log | sed -n '/Name:/s/^.*Name:\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/gp'
```

should do the job.

The biggest mistake that you had in your original expression is that you escaped the second parenthesis.  When I run your snippet, I get an error:

```
sed: 1: "s/Name:\(.*\)\)/\1/g": RE error: parentheses not balanced
```

Even if you correct that, you will find that sed prints every line by default.  Here is what the expression that I built up does.

Sed expressions take the form of `[address[,address]]function[arguments]`.  Your expression did not include either of the optional *address* elements.  I included a single *address* (`/Name:/`) which matches any line that contains "Name:".  The function is the *substitution* function which requires two arguments - (1) a search pattern and (2) a replacement expression.  The search pattern matches the entire line and extracts the segment of the line following "Name:" that contains zero or more characters until the first parenthesis.  The "escaped" parentheses define the capture group and the unescaped one terminates the capture.  The pattern includes the rest of the line (e.g., `.*$`).  Since the entire line is matched, it will be replaced by the replacement expression which contains only the captured portion.

Putting this all together, the simple sed statement matches any line containing "Name:" and replaces the entire line with the characters between `Name:` and the first left parenthesis (`)`).  The `-n` flag and the addition of the `p` flag ensures that only the matched lines are printed.

Comment: added a description of how the command works and where you went wrong

Comment: As your regexp is matching from the start (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the line the `g` flag is not necessary.

Comment: Neither is the address specification, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

you where close, try

```
echo "abc bcd def (task Name: example)" | sed 's/.*Name: \(.*\)[\)]/\1/'

**output**
example
```

OR even simpler

```
echo "abc bcd def (task Name: example)" | sed 's/.*Name: \(.*\))/\1/'
```

Note that you didn't need to escape your literal closing paren ')'.

OR (per request), with a variable

```
var="Name: "
echo "abc bcd def (task Name: example)" | sed "s/.\*${var}\(.\*\))/\1/"
```

**output**

```
example
```

Note the extra escape chars around the shell metacharacter '*'.

If your value of `var=` contains any shell metacharaters, you'll need to escape them as well.

IHTH

Comment: If I am going to use a variable (i.e $variable=Name:)  how to change the expression?

Comment: what if I need to grep the all words after "task" in expression "task: (abc def ghi )"  I tried the command 

    var="task:"
    sed -n "s/^${var}\(.*\)).*/\1/"

Comment: use the KISS approach of Unix commandline: add another `| grep def` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep

```
grep -oP '(?<=Name: )\w+(?=\))' script.log
```

Comment: hi..i want all line number & line data if pattern matched between '< and '>;

Comment: @MayurKukadiya Add the `-n` option to get the line numbers: `grep -noP '(?<=<).*(?=>;)' yourfile` or something like that.

Comment: i want match pattern between '<(single quot lessthan) and '>;(single quot greater than coma) and then copy all matched line one file to another and i try grep -noP '(?<=\'<).*(?='\>;)' < source.php >> destination.php but didn't copy

Comment: @MayurKukadiya Escaping of the single quote doesn't work like that, try changing the pattern to `"(?<='<).*(?='>;)"` (note the double quotes).

Comment: thnks lev..but .. data dont copy to destination .php file when i try  grep -noP "(?<='<).*(?='>;)" < source.php >> destination.php